# All Possible combinations in C

Tags: c, algorithm, combinatorics

I'm trying to find a efficient algorithm in C, which provides me all combinations of a given charset.

The algorithm should not recursive. At last the number of digits should be flexible. For example:

```
char set[] = "a1";
->
a1
aa
1a
11
```

I've only found a Perl solution, but it uses `substr()`. I think that wasn't that fast performance-wise.

For most algorithms in C, I've found were only permutations...

A article in a german C++ forum claims, that C++-STL Solutions are faster than "raw" recursive algorithms.

Comment: Why can't you convert the Perl solution to C?

Comment: why shouldn't it be recursive?  That sounds like an artificial constraint, typically for homework reasons.

Comment: You say `char set[] = "a1"; -> a1 aa 1a 11`. Why not aaa, aa1, a1a, a11, 1aa, 1a1, 11a and 111?

Comment: The problem is going to take almost exponential time anyway, and yes certain c++ implementations are faster because they use little tricks to make it faster, next_permutation for instance. I don't see a point in trying to optimize something that's going to be painfully slow for input of size greater than 10.

Comment: I smell homework..... no recursion.....

Comment: Some questions:  Why C++ tag?  Could charset include duplicate characters and if so, how should these be treated?

Comment: Since I am also willing to take the more efficient solution.

Comment: Does someone know a good source of Information/Code for this Problem.

Comment: I removed C++ since he's explicitly asking for C and added Homework, too many restrictions on something mundane not to be Homework.

Comment: More efficient in what respect O(n!) is still gonna be O(n!) your only really improving low end boundaries, try generating all combos/permutations of an input size of 15, you could get quite a lot done before you get a response.

Comment: No, the  charset could not contain redundant characters. char set[] = "a1"; -> a1 aa 1a 11. Why not aaa, aa1, a1a, a11, 1aa, 1a1, 11a was a good explaination from Oswald. So I wan't to pass the charset and the number of digits (3 in the above example)

Comment: I guess if you really want a fast solution you could just give me your professors email and I can send him my code with your name on it...

Answer (score 2):

If the set size were a fixed N it would be simple - you could just have N `for` loops, each one nested into the previous one. Since you can't do this and you can't use recursion, you have to calculate the total required number of iterations (seems like it's N^M), use one single loop and then use / and % to calculate what the array index of each character should be. You'd better use longs as well, because N^M gets big fast.

Comment: I know the solution with nested for loop's but it isn't flexible. I wan't to use the algo for some different problems.

Comment: Hah I was just about to point out n^m on complexity, looks like you beat me to it.

Comment: The reason for the ask is the following: I implemented the arc 4 algo and try to benchmarkt what time is needed for a bruteforce attack with a.) known plaintext b.) statistical analyssis of character frquency.

Comment: I hate to sound like a functional programming fanatic, but I still don't understand why you can't use recursion.

Comment: recursion in C is actually not a lot of overhead so I don't see the problem either.

Comment: a recursive solution is also ok. so I can pass the check function as parameter.

Answer (score 2):

Python is very close to a pseudo code.

You can read the Python source to [itertools.permutations](http://docs.python.org/library/itertools.html#itertools.permutations) and just replicate in C.

Here is the demo that this works:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
import itertools

s='a1'

print set(itertools.permutations(s*len(s), len(s)))
```

Output:

```
set([('1', '1'), ('a', '1'), ('a', 'a'), ('1', 'a')])
```

Here is an even simpler way:

```
>>> s='a1'
>>> ['{}{}'.format(x,y) for x in s for y in s]
['aa', 'a1', '1a', '11']


>>> s='abc'
>>> ['{}{}{}'.format(x,y,z) for x in s for y in s for z in s]
['aaa', 'aab', 'aac', 'aba', 'abb', 'abc', 'aca', 'acb', 
 'acc', 'baa', 'bab', 'bac', 'bba', 'bbb', 'bbc', 'bca', 
 'bcb', 'bcc', 'caa', 'cab', 'cac', 'cba', 'cbb', 'cbc', 
 'cca', 'ccb', 'ccc']
```

To unwind a list comprehension, use NESTED LOOPS, like so:

```
>>> for x in s:
...    for y in s:
...       for z in s:
...          print '{}{}{}'.format(x,y,z)
```

Answer (score 2):

Wikipedia has C code for the [n-ary Gray code](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gray_code#n-ary_Gray_code). It should be convertible to your problem by using the digits as offsets into your input array. You will need to do some dynamic allocation to handle the arbitrary length of your input. A related approach is to do nested loops, where you have an array of loop counters as long as your input, and another counter for which of those you are currently incrementing. E.g. printing all six-digit base-six numbers, needs to be modified for dynamic allocation but shows the principle:

```
int i;
int length = 5;
int max = 6;
int counters[length];
for (i=0; i<length; i++)
    counters[i] = 0;
for(;;) {
    for (i=length-1; i>=0; i--)
        printf("%d", counters[i]);
    printf("\n");
    for(i=0; i<length; i++) {
        counters[i]++;
        if (counters[i] < max)
            break;
        else
            counters[i] = 0;
    }
    if (i >= length)
        break;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Well, I would number the possible combinations, loop through the numbers and convert.

For instance: to generate all size 3 combinations of the 10 symbols {'0', '1', ..., '9'}, I would loop from 0 to 999 and output "000" to "999".

In the same way (kinda), to generate all size 3 combinations of the 5 symbols {'a', 'b', ..., 'e'} I would loop from 0 to 5*5*5-1 and output the loop number in base 5, but with the symbols provided.

Answer (score 0):

Write a function that will convert an integer into a string hexadecimal number, then convert that algorithm into a base 36 (a-z plus 0-9) number. Use one for loop to count from 1 to (digit count times base) and call your function each time.

- 1 becomes 1
- 10 becomes a
- 35 becomes z
- 36 becomes 10
- 46 becomes 1a

Comment: So, I found a recursive solution. http://www.daniweb.com/software-development/cpp/threads/50604. I want to try also some other solutions to check the performance.