# Numerical Combinations in C

Tags: c++, algorithm

I can't come up with a generic code for a problem like this example

I have 1, 2, and 3 in a vector or 12345.... depending on the input.

There are 6 possible combinations without repeating the same numbers again

123
132
213
231
321
312

Can anyone help?

This is one of the functions I use. I have another for the actual combination

```
void troca(int *a, int *b)
{
    int x;

    x=*a;
    *a=*b;
    *b=x;
}
```

Comment: that function `troca` just swaps the numbers, that's not really relevant to the problem.  Check out this question, it describes the algorithm you need to implement: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5627209/all-possible-combinations-in-c?rq=1

Comment: You can check it out, this question is also about string permutations in C:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9148543/program-to-print-permutations-of-given-elements/9148657#9148657

Answer (score 4):

Are you using c++? (You mentioned vector)

Try [next_permutation](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/algorithm/next_permutation/)